# How does this sorting algorithm function?

Tags: java, sorting

I was looking for a sorting algorithm and found the following which does the work. Yet I don't understand what does the first part do? Thanks for your help/comments!

```
public static void reorder (Animal[] types) {
      int i = 0, j;                   //From here
      for (Animal type : types)
         if (type.ordinal() > 0) 
            i++;                      //to here
      for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
         types[j] = Animal.rabbit;
      for (i = j; i < balls.length; i++)
         types[i] = Animal.fox;
```

Comment: Why not just step through it or "play computer" on paper? There's not much going on. (And I'd be wary of calling this a "sorting algorithm" in the general sense.)

Comment: And as part of stepping through it, consider breaking it down into smaller parts. Ask yourself what the first loop does, and then what the second two do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `Animal` has an `ordinal()` method, not sure what that method does but the section of code you refer to does:

- Iterate the `types` array
- If the invocation of the method `ordinal()` on each element is greater than 0

  - Then it increases the counter `i` in by 1

And that's it really.